# Mystery printer cannot be deleted

Tags: printing

I was having problems with CUPS constantly adding a printer which couldn't be used to the printer list. I googled around and acting on info found I altered /etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf. The line I changed was from

> BrowseRemoteProtocols dnssd cups

to

> BrowseRemoteProtocols none

This only made it impossible to find my printer and so I reverted back to the original.

Since reverting back to the original /etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf CUPS has stopped adding printers (great) but the a printer called "print" appears in the list of available printer when I want to print something, like this:
[image]

The comment in English reads "Task rejected". I cannot delete this printer and it does not appear in the printer configuration list:[image]

How can I delete the printer called "print"?

Comment: Are there any jobs for this "printer" still running? Perhaps you need to cancel these first.

Comment: I have tried everything I can to stop all possible print jobs, including running lprm -

Comment: If I click in the printer "print" there appears the message "Getting printer information" and a time-wheel but the action never stops until I stop it manually.

Comment: As a last resort: `sudo systemctl stop cups`, make a backup of `/etc/cups/printers.conf`,  then do `sudo nano /etc/cups/printers.conf`, find the dummy printer between `<Printer ...>` and `</Printer>`, delete these lines, save the file, then do `sudo systemctl start cups`.

Comment: I stopped CUPS and tried to edit printers.conf but all it contained were the lines # Printer configuration file for CUPS v2.2.10
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING

Comment: Ok. Then try: `sudo apt purge cups`, then `sudo apt install cups` and add your printer.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that first thing tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: No luck. I stopped and then purged CUPS, cleaned apt afterwards and then restarted CUPS and the "print" and PDF options were the only printers shown. I re-booted my laptop and the real printer was back alongside the "print" non-printer which never went away.